# Twitter Name Validation

Tags: regex, twitter

In our registration form we now want to ask the user to enter their twitter name (eg @paul).

Can anyone tell what characters are allowed in it?

e.g.    a-z, A-Z, underscores, 0-9

anything else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I *believe* it's letters, numbers and underscores only, and a maximum of 15 characters.

A quick search unveiled this post (non-Twitter) covering the same topic:

http://kagan.mactane.org/blog/2009/09/22/what-characters-are-allowed-in-twitter-usernames/

The above post also contains regex examples to help you validate:

```
Full regex – /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}$/
Perl-compatible regex – /^\w{1,15}$/
```

Comment: one extra thing worth noting is, that the 15 char limit was at one time 20 chars.  You may need to adjust your regex or whatever to cater for older names.

Answer (score 4):

This is the final JavaScript Funcion:

```
function validTwitteUser(sn) {
    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}$/.test(sn);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this page from Twitter for the official guidelines/rules

http://support.twitter.com/articles/101299-why-can-t-i-register-certain-usernames#

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the regexes here seem all correct, they all allow for less than 4 characters to pass validation. As per [twitter](http://support.twitter.com/articles/101299-why-can-t-i-register-certain-usernames#):

- Your username cannot be longer than 15 characters. Your name can be
  longer (50 characters) or shorter than 4 characters, but usernames
  are kept shorter for the sake of ease.
- A username can only contain alphanumeric characters (letters A-Z,
  numbers 0-9) with the exception of underscores, as noted above. Check
  to make sure your desired username doesn't contain any symbols,
  dashes, or spaces.

So therefore, the correct regex is:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{4,15}$/
```

If one were to nit-pick then you also can't use the word Twitter or Admin, for my purposes the above suffices.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript / TypeScript:

Firstly,

```sh
npm i twitter-text
# or
yarn add twitter-text
```

Then,

```js
import { isValidUsername } from 'twitter-text'

console.log(isValidUsername('@helloworld')) // true
```

There are other implementations (Java, Ruby, ObjC), please take a look at https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text

---

Note: the bundle size is too large for merely a string validation...